# python ndarray update exiting function

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, assignment-operator

I have the following loop in a function definition:

```
mu=np.zeros((T,p))
mu_post=np.zeros((T,p))

for t in arange(T):
      mu_post[t]= np.dot(a,b)
      mu[t+1]= mu_post[t]
      some other processing
```

After reaching towards end of the cycle (t=T-1), the code exits this function without executing it through. However, on trying to debug, if I manually (in pycharm debug console) try to do mu[t+1]= mu_post[t], it works fine. Could there be a reason for this. BTW, I tried doing mu[t+1][:]= mu_post[t] but it has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

> the code exits this function without executing it through.

this is vague, but I suspect I can reproduce the error with this:

```
In [47]: mu=np.zeros((5,3))
In [48]: mu1=np.zeros((5,3))

In [49]: for t in range(5):
   ....:     mu1[t,:]=[1,2,3]
   ....:     mu[t+1,:] = mu1[t]

----> 3     mu[t+1,:] = mu1[t]

IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5
```

At the last iteration, `t==4`, so `t+1` is `5`.  That is too large of an index for the 1st dimension of `mu`.

Why are you indexing `mu` with `t+1`?  And if that makes sense, why is `mu` the same size as `mu1`?